# Clickable checkBox text in android with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, kotlin

I am creating an android app with `kotlin`. I have reached a point that I have an EULA (End User License Agreement) `checkbox` and I need to make a part of the text of the check box clickable in order to display the terms and conditions.

> **XML file**

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/accept_terms_and_conditions"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="I have read and accept the Terms &amp; Conditions"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

I want to have the `Terms & Conditions` part clickable. I have already tried the code below. This was initially `java` code found [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/clickablespan) and it was transformed to `kotlin` automatically by `Android Studio` but I didn't have much luck with it as the app crashes when the `SignUpActivity` starts.

> **Kotlin file**

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mAuthTask: UserSignUpTask? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)


        val checkBox = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.accept_terms_and_conditions)

        val text = getText(R.string.terms_and_conditions)

        val ss = SpannableString(text)

        val clickableSpan1 = object : ClickableSpan() {

            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds)
                ds.color = Color.BLUE
                ds.isUnderlineText = false
            }
        }

        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 28, 46, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        checkBox.text = ss
        checkBox.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
}
```

So is there any way to do this from the `XML` file directly? And if not how can I do it in `Kotlin`?

Note: The API I am developing the app is 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from @Karan Mer and some of the code found [here](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/clickablespan) the problem is solved so I will present the overall solution here.

> XML file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_Layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/accept_terms_and_conditions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Terms_and_condition_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:text="I have read and accept the Terms & Conditions"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

> Kotlin file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)



    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Terms_and_condition_text)

    val text = getText(R.string.terms_and_conditions)

    val ss = SpannableString(text)

    val clickableSpan1 = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            //here you can set it to do whatever you want when clicked
        }


        //This is in order to change the default appereance of the link
        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.color = Color.BLUE
            ds.isUnderlineText = false
        }
    }

    //here you set the starting and ending char of the link in the string
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan1, 28, 45, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    textView.text = ss
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
}
```

Comment: This is getting background color on click of textview, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, Use horizontal LinearLayout with CheckBox with no text and TextView that you want to show as checkbox text. Now you can individually handle clicks on both checkbox and textview.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I agree to terms and conditions"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Result looks like below.

[image]

Comment: And then how can i set only the `Terms and Conditions` part clickable?

Comment: set click listener to only textview.

Comment: This will set the hole textveiw as clickable and I only want the `Terms & Conditions` part so I can make it blue and look like a link like you see in most EULA checkboxes

Comment: I am looking for something like [this](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/clickablespan) but in `kotlin`.

Comment: you can set width of textview to wrapcontent, so it will be practically similar to clicking your text unless you provide bigger enough padding. regarding changing color of text it will be easy.

Comment: But still I want only some part of the text clickable. I tried to use two `TextView` tags next to each other but the problem is that my text in small screens turns out to be 2 lines so the text doesn't line up (I get the text of the first `TextView` in two lines and next to it the text of the second `TextView` in two lines as well).

Comment: then setting clickable span to portion of text in textview should work.

Comment: I have added a solution based on your clickable span comment that worked for me with no problems even in multi line text, so future readers can find the answer easy without searcing in comments